# Unable to get the output in an organized manner

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape some item `names` along with `review texts` and `reviewers` connected to each item name from a webpage using their api. The thing is my below script can do those things partially. I need to do those in an organized manner.

For example, in each item `name` there are multiple `review texts` and `reviewer names` connected to it. I wish to get them along the columns like:

`Name` `review text` `reviewer` `review text` `reviewer` -----

Basically, I can't get the idea how to make use of the already defined `for loop` in the right way within my script. Lastly, there are few item `names` which do not have any `reviews` or `reviewers`, so the code breaks when it doesn't find any `reviews` and so.

This s my approach so far:

```
import requests

url = "https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/restaurants/{}?yelp_site="

res = requests.get("https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/locales/madison-wi/restaurants")
for item in res.json():
    itemid = item['id']
    req = requests.get(url.format(itemid))
    name = req.json()['name']
    for texualreviews in req.json()['yelpReviews']:
        reviews = texualreviews['message']
        reviewer = texualreviews['reviewerName']
        print(f'{name}\n{reviews}\n{reviewer}\n')
```

If I use print statement outside the for loop, It only gives me a single `review` and `reviewer`.

Any help to fix that will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the review and a reviewer name to an array to display as you wish.

Try the following code.

```
review_data = dict()
review_data['name'] = req.json()['name']
review_data['reviews'] = []
for texualreviews in req.json()['yelpReviews']:
    review_sub_data = {'review': texualreviews['message'], 'reviewer': texualreviews['reviewerName']}
    review_data['reviews'].append(review_sub_data)
#O/P {'name': 'xxx', 'reviews':[{'review':'xxx', 'reviewer': 'xxx'}, {'review':'xxx', 'reviewer': 'xxx'}]}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I execute your suggested script, it throws an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo000000.py", line 65, in <module>
    review_data['reviews'].append(review_data)
KeyError: 'reviews'`

Comment: I have made the edit. The problem was with the variable name. Check the code now.

Comment: It seems to be working in the right way until it hits a container where there is no `yelpReviews` connected to a name. Can you tell me how to bypass that error because few names do not have reviews. Btw, this is the error I get in the halfway `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo000000.py", line 101, in <module>
    for texualreviews in req.json()['yelpReviews']:
KeyError: 'yelpReviews'`.

Comment: Use try except for that